# Let be $F$ a Field, show that $M_{m\times n}(K) \simeq F^m \otimes F^n $

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let be $F$ a Field, show that $M_{m\times n}(F) \simeq F^m \otimes F^n $

I try for $u=(u_1,...,u_m) \in F^m$ and $w=(w_1,...,w_n)\in F^n$
I defined $\psi: F^m \times F^n \rightarrow M_{m\times n}(F)$

such that $\psi(u,w)=(u_iw_j)_{m\times n}$

this is $\psi(u,w)=\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1w_1 & ..... & u_1w_n\\
. &  & \\
. &  & \\
u_mw_1 & .... &u_mw_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$

SO $\psi$ is bilineal and then there is an unique lineal application $L:F^m \otimes F^n \rightarrow M_{m\times n}$

such that $L(t_{mn})=\psi(u,w)$ but how can i show that is bijective in the basis and then induces an isomorphism? What can i do? or im doing wrong?

Comment: An isomorphism as $K$-vector spaces?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, it was $F$ i just corrected it

Comment: Do you know anything about how to find a basis for a tensor product?

Comment: @EricWofsey i know that a basis for $F^m \otimes F^n$ will be all the pairs $(u_i,w_j) \in F^m \times F^n $

Comment: @EricWofsey where $u_i$ and $w_j$ are the canonical basis for $F^m$ and $F^n$

Comment: Alright, now you just have to check that your $L$ maps that basis to a basis for $M_{m\times n}$.

Comment: Also, you're showing these are vector spaces of the same dimension, so you're pretty much done.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think im stuck in that any hint?